# How to use float values for mouse position in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, position, mouse

I'm coding a space-invaders like game, and I want to be able to move the player controlled ship with both mouse and keyboard. There is a speed constant that is being used, when moving the ship with the keyboard. When moving the ship with the mouse, only the position of the ship is changed. When moving the ship with the keyboard, the position of the mouse is also changed, to be consistent with the position of the ship.

The constant I mentioned is not an int value, but a float one. The reason behind this is that I want to add a powerup to increase the speed of the ship, and that may or may not be of type int. Also, I wish to be able to fine tune the speed, if requested by players or by game being to difficult. Problem is, the MouseState gives me a pair of int coordinates, but the position of the ship is a pair of float ones. So herein lies the problem :

Each frame, I need to move the ship to the mouse position (mouse controlled), and each frame I need to move the mouse position to the ship (keyboard controlled). Since the mouse gives me int coordinates, the float ones from the ship's position must be converted to int, which destroyes the idea I described earlier. Is there any way I can force the mouse to use float coordinates, either a workaround in XNA or some other API (DirectX or WINAPI)? I'm also toying with the idea of virtual coordinates and screen coordinates, with conversion between them.

Cheers,
Alex

EDIT : Added code snippet :

```
if (_keybState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
{
    Mouse.SetPosition(
    (int)(_player1.GetPlayerPosition().X + Constants.HorizontalMovementSpeed), 
    (int)(_player1.GetPlayerPosition().Y));
}
if (_keybState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
{
    Mouse.SetPosition(
        (int)(_player1.GetPlayerPosition().X - Constants.HorizontalMovementSpeed),
        (int)(_player1.GetPlayerPosition().Y));
}
if (_keybState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
{
    Mouse.SetPosition(
        (int)(_player1.GetPlayerPosition().X ),
        (int)(_player1.GetPlayerPosition().Y - Constants.VerticalMovementSpeed));
}
if (_keybState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
{
    Mouse.SetPosition(
        (int)(_player1.GetPlayerPosition().X),
        (int)(_player1.GetPlayerPosition().Y + Constants.VerticalMovementSpeed));
}
if (_keybState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && _shootKeyPressed == false)
{
    _player1.Shoot();
    _shootKeyPressed = true;
}

_shoboState = Mouse.GetState();
_player1.MovePlayerShipToPosition(new Vector2(_shoboState.X, _shoboState.Y));
```

Comment: Can you control the mouse position with the keyboard and just have the ship follow the mouse?

Comment: I could, but the same problem appears. When using the Mouse.SetPosition method, I need to specify int coordinates, so the float coordinate of the new, future position of the ship get rounded. The effect of this is that the ship moves in one direction faster than in the opposite direction

Comment: Then I don't understand. I thought your ship moved a fixed distance towards the mouse each frame?

Comment: Also, it would be good if you posted some code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Store two sets of coordinates.  One set for the ship's position (float), and one for the mouse position (int) that is a rounded version of the ship's position.  If not, write a mouse wrapper that works with floats.

Comment: @Phil I added the code snippet containing your suggestion to the post. The rounding occurs after adding/substracting the same amount. After adding, the result after rounding is the same as rounding the added value and adding the result to the position; at substraction however, rounding the resulted value loses one additional unit. Say, coordinate is 100 and speed constant is 2.3 (int)(100+2.3)=102, but (int)(100-2.3)=97(?!); it moves left faster than right and upwards faster than down.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the suggestions, I will look into them

Comment: Oh, in that case you just need to cast your `2.3` to an `int` **before** you add it to your coordinate. If you do that you'll be adding/subtracting a flat 2.0 each time.

Comment: Indeed, but then the idea of using a floating point speed value would be obsolete, which is not what I'm trying to implement... Powerup for speed would, for example, increase the speed by 0.5, so casting it to int is not a solution for my particular issue...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tying the mouse and ship positions together like this:

```
_shoboState = Mouse.GetState();
_player1.MovePlayerShipToPosition(new Vector2(_shoboState.X, _shoboState.Y));
```

Try something along these lines:

1. Find unit vector between mouse and ship. This will give you a 1 unit step from your ship to your mouse. (You should be able to find tutorials for this fairly easily)
2. Multiply the unit vector by your movement amount. This gives you a direction and distance for you to move your ship.
3. Apply new vector to your ship.
4. Move the mouse as close as you can to your ship's new position.

Comment: Problem is, that I actually [i]want[/i] to use floating point numbers. When using a speed powerup which, for example, changes the speed from 2 to 3, the change is actually very high, so working with floating point numbers is a must in my case.